# What causes org-open-at-point command to fail?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-link

For some reason doom emacs fails to open links that point to a local file (`[[file:firejail.html][file]]`). It's X11 KDE Arch doom emacs and if opened with xdg-open default application to open .html files works correctly (librewolf).

Messages claims that it's `Running open /mnt/notes/firejail.html` but nothing happens.

I'm tracing it with edebugger all the way to the `org-open-file` function hoping that some bug will come up. The problem appears to be that values in `org-file-apps` get mixed with values obtained with the `org--file-default-apps` run as part of the `org-open-file` function. One of these values appears to be `(t . mailcap)`, which seems to take precedence over `("\\.x?html?\\'" . default)`.

Has anyone come across this before? Are there any common bugs on KDE with `org-open-file`? Any rules of thumb/workarounds?

Comment: I presume that https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/78073/exporting-org-files-to-html-ox-pandoc-results-in-error-in-process-sentinel  is a precursor of this question and can be closed with a reference to this one?

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. Yes, I've just closed it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be incorrect .mailcap file:

```
text/html; open %s; nametemplate=%s.html
...
```

changing it to:

```
text/html; /usr/bin/xdg-open %s; nametemplate=%s.html
...
```

made it work. `open` I believe is a MacOS thing, not sure how it got there.

I managed to solve it by painstakingly tracing function call by function call and setting up edebugger to display local variables in backtrace, so it became clear at some point that there is a check against `org-file-apps` contents that was changed to contain mailcap.

By the way `edebug-toggle-locals` for debugging is such a useful tool!